# Nested macro with variadic arguments does compile in GCC but not in MSVC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, visual-c++, macros

I created a macro with boost/preprocessor to repetitively create code. The reason for this is that I work on a very restricted target hardware with a very restricted compiler, that doesn't support arrays.

The code I came up with is follows:

```cpp
# define ESC(...) __VA_ARGS__
# define IF_BODY(n, condition, lhs, rhs, arg1, arg2) \
if (condition > n) { \
    lhs##n.arg1 = rhs[n].arg1; \
    lhs##n.arg2 = rhs[n].arg2; \
}
# define IF_BODY_(A, B) IF_BODY(A, B)
# define IF_QUERY(z, n, vars) IF_BODY_(n, ESC vars)

BOOST_PP_REPEAT(3, IF_QUERY, \
        (index, variableName, otherVariableName, latitude, longitude))
```

It's aim is to create several if queries with ascending conditions.

I tested this code on godbolt with the gcc and it works like a charm, as you can [see here](https://godbolt.org/z/QUze_R).
Now when I try the same in the MSVC it doesn't compile. There error is C2065, e.g. "variableName" is not declared. [See it here on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/LmiPWe).

Why is that? Is this a bug in MSVC? Are these types of macros just not supported in MSVC? Is there an error in my code?

Comment: You most likely don't know, though, you can just tell compiler explorer to add boost as a library. See the book icon

Comment: I knew. But I manually added the headers to check if the problem has something to do with godbolt. That's what's ended up in the question. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My investigation makes me believe this is a bug in MSVC.

If I change the code to the following and do a pre-process to file (note that my 'coord' and 'variableName', 'otherVariableName' identifiers are just to make those parts of your code match something, and note how I have reversed your IF_BODY and IF_BODY_ and that IF_BODY_ is commented out by the #if 0):

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repeat.hpp>

struct coord
{
    int latitude, longitude;
};

# define ESC_(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define ESC(vars) ESC_ vars

#if 0
# define IF_BODY_(n, condition, lhs, rhs, arg1, arg2) \
if (condition > n) { \
    lhs##n.arg1 = rhs[n].arg1; \
lhs##n.arg2 = rhs[n].arg2; \
}
#endif

# define IF_BODY(A, B) IF_BODY_(A, ESC(B))

# define IF_QUERY(z, n, vars) IF_BODY(n, vars)

int main()
{
    int index;
    coord variableName0, otherVariableName0;
    coord variableName1, otherVariableName1;
    coord variableName1, otherVariableName1;
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(3, IF_QUERY, (index, variableName, otherVariableName, latitude, longitude))
}
```

I get the following:

```
int main()
{
    int index;
    coord variableName0, otherVariableName0;
    coord variableName1, otherVariableName1;
    coord variableName1, otherVariableName1;
    IF_BODY_(0, index, variableName, otherVariableName, latitude, longitude)
    IF_BODY_(1, index, variableName, otherVariableName, latitude, longitude)
    IF_BODY_(2, index, variableName, otherVariableName, latitude, longitude)
}
```

Note that the macro call has the correct number of arguments. However, if I change the #if 0 to #if 1 I get the following compiler output:
tester\tester.cpp(35): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'IF_BODY_'

Looking at the preprocessed results in that case:

```
int main()
{
    int index;
    coord variableName0, otherVariableName0;
    coord variableName1, otherVariableName1;
    coord variableName1, otherVariableName1;
    if (index, variableName, otherVariableName, latitude, longitude > 0) { 0. = [0].; 0. = [0].; } 
    if (index, variableName, otherVariableName, latitude, longitude > 1) { 1. = [1].; 1. = [1].; } 
    if (index, variableName, otherVariableName, latitude, longitude > 2) { 2. = [2].; 2. = [2].; }
}
```

It seems that MSVC performs the macro variable assignment before performing the ESC expansion, that all of the contents of B get assigned to 'condition' rather than being broken out to the correct IF_BODY_ arguments. I will be submitting this as feedback through the MSVS Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a problem mechanism.

--

Okay, I have managed to find a solution but it is *very* ugly. It requires a variadic extension to the BOOST_PP_REPEAT family (which I have only partly implemented here). It may be worth submitting this as a suggestion to boost but I am not sure that boost.preprocessor is still maintained. And note how the ESC_/ESC macros are simply gone in this version.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repeat.hpp>

# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_1_V(m, d, ...) m(2, 0, d, __VA_ARGS__)
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_2_V(m, d, ...) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_1_V(m, d, __VA_ARGS__) m(2, 1, d, __VA_ARGS__)
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_3_V(m, d, ...) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_2_V(m, d, __VA_ARGS__) m(2, 2, d, __VA_ARGS__)
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_4_V(m, d, ...) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_3_V(m, d, __VA_ARGS__) m(2, 3, d, __VA_ARGS__)
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_I_V(c, m, d, ...) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_ ## c##_V(m, d, __VA_ARGS__)
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_V(c, m, d, ...) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_I_V(c, m, d, __VA_ARGS__)

#define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_V BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_, BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_P, 4)), _V)


struct coord
{
    int latitude, longitude;
};

#if 1
# define IF_BODY_(n, condition, lhs, rhs, arg1, arg2) \
if (condition > n) { \
    lhs##n.arg1 = rhs[n].arg1; \
lhs##n.arg2 = rhs[n].arg2; \
}
#endif

#define ESC_(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define ESC(a) ESC_(a)
#define IF_BODY(a, ...) ESC_(IF_BODY_(a, __VA_ARGS__))
# define IF_QUERY(z, n, ...) IF_BODY(n, __VA_ARGS__)


int main()
{
    int index = 0;
    coord variableName0, variableName1, variableName2;
    coord otherVariableName[3];

    BOOST_PP_REPEAT_V(3, IF_QUERY, index, variableName, otherVariableName, latitude, longitude)
}
```

the new code expands to:

```
int main()
{
    int index = 0;
    coord variableName0, variableName1, variableName2;
    coord otherVariableName[3];

    if (index > 0) { variableName0.latitude = otherVariableName[0].latitude; variableName0.longitude = otherVariableName[0].longitude; } 
    if (index > 1) { variableName1.latitude = otherVariableName[1].latitude; variableName1.longitude = otherVariableName[1].longitude; } 
    if (index > 2) { variableName2.latitude = otherVariableName[2].latitude; variableName2.longitude = otherVariableName[2].longitude; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your investigation! Do you think there is a way to bypass this bug?

Comment: Take a look at my expanded answer, I did find a way around this. But like I said it is very ugly. A better way might be to work with the compiler (even gcc) instead of against and use boost preprocessor's TUPLE macros (which would also necessitate getting rid of ESC in order that the grouped parameters be passed as a unit).

Comment: Nice! Also thanks for the hint with the TUPLE macro, I use this now and it works like a charm. [This is how it looks like now](https://godbolt.org/z/s16JK1).